# unable to get a response from http server

Tags: android, http

I'm trying to do a post to a url by sending a username and a password using the post method.But the answer is unclear.

Here is how I do it:

```
HttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost  httppost=new HttpPost("http://test.res-novae.fr/xperia_orange/scripts/android_ckeck_user.php");
        try{

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));   


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        /*Checking response*/
        if(response!=null)
        {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            System.out.println("Resultat de la server:"+in);
        }
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {

        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

and this is the answer from server:

```
Resultat de la server:org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@44e067e0
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the stream, but are rather looking at a `String` representation of the underlying `InputStream` object.

You will want to read the contents of the `InputStream`.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-a-read-convert-an-inputstream-in-to-a-string) for examples of how to do this.